# How to write this query as lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm still having problems to write lambda expressions that should create some object and to set properties with the object initializer.

How would this query be written as a lambda expression?

```
List<CategoryContainer> _catList = (from q in _dc.Category
                                   select new CategoryContainer
                                   {
                                     IDCategory = q.IDCategory,
                                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you really need the .ToList() here?  Unnecessary .ToList() calls are a common source of performance drains.

Comment: You got any comparision data to that statement? I do prefer List<> over the var thing.

Comment: It's a matter of what you're going to do with it. If you're going to iterate over it more than once, ToList() is good. Otherwise, it's silly. You don't need to use var either way: if you don't do ToList(), you want IEnumerable<CategoryContainer> _catList = ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
dc.Category.Select(q => new CategoryContainer {
                       IDCategory = q.IDCategory,
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is ConvertAll:

```
dc.Category.ConvertAll<CategoryContainer>( q => new CategoryContainer { 
IDCategory = q.IDCategory, }).ToList();
```

Comment: `ConvertAll` is a method on `List<T>`.  If `dc.Category` isn't a `List<T>`, `ConvertAll` will not exist.  Also, `ConvertAll` already returns a `List<T>`, so there's no point in calling `ToList`.

Comment: Very good point, I made assumptions based on the code snippet.  But this is an option for apps using .NET 2 with the use of a delegate, since Linq didn't exist until later (even though the question author is clearly using Linq).